# How to use terraform output as input variable of another terraform template

Tags: terraform

Is there any way I can use a Terraform template output to another Terraform template's input?

Ex: I have a Terraform template which creates an ELB and I have another Terraform template which is going to create an auto scale group which need the ELB information as an input variable.

I know I can use shell script to `grep` and feed in the ELB information, but I'm looking for some Terraform way to doing this.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried using remote state to populate your second template?

Declare it like this:

```
resource "terraform_remote_state" "your_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "${var.your_bucket}"
    region = "${var.your_region}"
    key = "${var.your_state_file}"
  }
}
```

And then you should be able to pull out your resource directly like this:

```
your_elb = "${terraform_remote_state.your_state.output.your_output_resource}"
```

If this doesn't work for you, have you tried implementing your ELB in a module and then just using the output?

https://github.com/terraform-community-modules/tf_aws_elb is a good example of how to structure the module.

Comment: should your_elb = "${terraform_remote_state.your_state.outputs.your_output_resource}" - outputs instead of output

Comment: Check out the accurate syntax at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html

Comment: I'm using this, though the latest syntax is just `your_elb = terraform_remote_state.your_state.output.your_output_resource`

Comment: @ChrisF it's plural though, `outputs` instead of `output`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like in newer versions of Terraform you'd access the output var like this

```
your_elb = "${data.terraform_remote_state.your_state.your_output_resource}"
```

All the rest is the same, just how you referenced it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about ELB, but I will give an example with S3. It is less things to write.
If you don't know how to store terraform state on AWS, read the [article](https://www.lisenet.com/2020/terraform-with-aws-s3-and-dynamodb-for-remote-state-files).

Let's suppose you have two independent projects: **project-1**, **project-2**. They are located in two different directories (two different repositories)!

Terraform file **/tmp/project-1/main.tf**:

```
// Create an S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "main_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-epic-test-b1"
  acl    = "private"
}

// Output. It will available on s3://multi-terraform-project-state-bucket/p1.tfstate
output "bucket_name_p1" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.main_bucket.bucket
}

// Store terraform state on AWS. The S3 bucket and dynamo db table should be created before running terraform
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "multi-terraform-project-state-bucket"
    key = "p1.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "multi-terraform-project-state-table"
    region  = "eu-central-1" // AWS region of state resources
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "my-cli-profile" // User profile defined in ~/.aws/credentials
  region = "eu-central-1" // AWS region
}
```

You run **terraform init**, and **terraform apply**.

After it you move to the terraform file **/tmp/project-2/main.tf**:

```
// Create an S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "main_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-epic-test-b2"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    // Get the S3 bucket name from another terraform state file. In this case it is s3://multi-terraform-project-state-bucket/p1.tfstate
    p1-bucket = data.terraform_remote_state.state1.outputs.bucket_name_p1
  }
}

// Get date from another state file
data "terraform_remote_state" "state1" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "multi-terraform-project-state-bucket"
    key = "p1.tfstate"
    region  = "eu-central-1"
  }
}

// Store terraform state on AWS. The S3 bucket and dynamo db table should be created before running terraform
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "multi-terraform-project-state-bucket"
    key = "p2.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "multi-terraform-project-state-table"
    region  = "eu-central-1" // AWS region of state resources
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "my-cli-profile" // User profile defined in ~/.aws/credentials
  region = "eu-central-1" // AWS region
}
```

You run **terraform init**, and **terraform apply**.

Now check the tags in the **my-epic-test-b2**. You will find there the name of the bucket from the **project-1**.

Answer (score 0):

When you are integrating terraform with Jenkins you can simply define a variable in the Jenkinsfile you are creating. Suppose you want to run ec2-instance using terraform and Jenkinsfile. So when you need to get the public IP address of the instance you can use this command inside your Jenkinsfile.

```
script {
  def public_ip = sh(script: 'terraform output public_ip | cut -d \'\"\' -f2', returnStdout: true).trim()                      
}
```

This makes proper formatting and saves only the IP address in the public_ip variable. To do that you have to define the output block in the terraform script to output the public ip