# Can I Pass Terraform output / resources.id values into any variable present in variable.tf file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I need to have **"client_secret"** output value as an input for *"tenant_app_password"*

> variables.tf

```
variable "tenant_app_password" {
  description = ""
}
```

> Create-service-principal.tf

```
resource "random_string" "password" {
  length  = 32
  special = true
}

# Create Service Principal Password
 resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "test_sp_pwd" {
 service_principal_id =  azuread_service_principal.test_sp.id
 value                = random_string.password.result
 end_date       = "2020-01-12T07:10:53+00:00" 
}
```

> OUTPUT

```
output "client_secret" {
  value     = "${azuread_service_principal_password.wvd_sp_pwd.value}"
  sensitive = true
}
```

Is we have any possible way ???

Comment: Are these two separate modules?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to use the output of one Terraform run in another one. You can do this by using a [remote state datasource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) provider.

You cannot put the original output in a variable, but you can use the remote output as a variable directly in another template. For example, in your second template:

```
// set up the remote state data source

data "terraform_remote_state" "foo" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    bucket  = "<your bucket name>"
    key     = "<your statefile name.tfstate"
    region  = "<your region>"
  }
}


// use it 

resource "kubernetes_secret" "bar" {
  metadata {
    name = "bar"
  }

  data = {
    client_secret = data.terraform_remote_state.foo.outputs.client_secret
  }

}
```

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596412/how-to-use-terraform-output-as-input-variable-of-another-terraform-template).